# Why does displaying the kind of Option and Map using :kind work, but not for Function1?

Tags: scala, types

Why do I get the kinds of `Option` and `Map` using `:kind` in REPL of Scala **2.11.5** while it doesn't work for `Function1`? What's so special about `scala.Function1` and how to know it using the tools offered by Scala REPL?

```
scala> :k Option
scala.Option's kind is F[+A]

scala> :k Map
scala.collection.immutable.Map's kind is F[A1,+A2]

scala> :k Function1
<console>:8: error: not found: value Function1
              Function1
              ^
scala> :k scala.Function1
scala.Function1's kind is F[-A1,+A2]
```

Comment: I don't think `:k` has anything to do with it. Simply typing `Function1` is not found. Nor does `import scala._` or `import scala.Function1` resolve that. I'd like to know why that import does not work, and the fully qualified package name is required here.

Comment: @m-z `import Function1` works. It's a trait though, not an object/class, so getting its kind might not work.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Strangely, it does not for me. `:k` aside. Even referring to it in the REPL does not work, unless I refer to it as `scala.Function1`

Comment: @m-z Only works for me if I drop the `scala. ` prefix. What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`Map` and `Option` are in [Predef](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L92), but `scala.Function1` is there as only as `Function` (probably because `scala.Function1` already has a syntactic sugar).